# move files by names (variable last letter) to folder

Tags: powershell

We have a systeem at work where we change the last letter of the name of a file if we make a new version.  We change it alphabetic and O is the firstone and then A,B,C,... 
[image]

But the older versions don't need to stay in that folder any more.  I am looking for a "simpel" solution in powershell to move this older files to a folder "old".

I don't know how to start in powershell (except to move to the right folder) and don't know if it is possible.
Any suggestions can help.

```
Set-Location -Path "Z:\PDF\2018\18-00190 StBV THV Depret Franki\2D"
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property name
```

Comment: would you _require_ using the terminal letter to decide which one to move? it's far simpler to use the last modified timestamp ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey timestamp is not reliable. It could be accidentally changed for a lot of reasons.

Comment: ok. [*grin*] so ... since i have real problems doing code without any sample data ... and i refuse to type stuff in that you already have ... would you please post some samples? NOT a picture ... text that can copied & used.

Comment: Set-Location -Path "Z:\PDF\2018\18-00190 StBV THV Depret Franki\2D"
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property name

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain additional/updated information,don't put that into comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell you tend to work a lot with pipelines, creating sequences of objects and filtering, projecting or otherwise manipulating them along the way. Your problem could be solved as follows in a few steps (whether they're simple or not remains to be seen, but your requirements necessitate some custom code):

1. First group all files by their base file name without the suffix

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -File | Group-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_[A-O](?=$|\.)' }
   ```

   This creates a grouping key which is basically the file name without the *last-changed* suffix. Then we have for each group all revisions that have been created for that file. E.g. for your file names `1409-EM-M-PL-7000_A.dwg.pdf` you'd get a group named `1409-EM-M-PL-7000.dwg.pdf` containing all versions of that file.

   I'm assuming here that no letter beyond `O` will actually be used, but you can adapt the regex if necessary.
2. Sort the revisions in order:

   ```
   ForEach-Object {
       $_.Group | Sort-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_O(?=$|\.)', '_0' } -Descending
   }
   ```

   We replace the `_O` temporarily with `_0` for sorting here to get the correct order since it's the *oldest* but would usually appear as the latest version.

   We also sort descending here (so we get the latest versions first) to make the next step easier, since we actually want to grab the files we have to move, not those we want to retain.
3. Retain the latest *n* versions by grabbing every file *except* the latest 3 in this case:

   ```
   Select-Object -Skip 3
   ```
4. Move the remaining files to `old`:

   ```
   Move-Item -Destination old
   ```

Putting it all together:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |
  Group-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_[A-O](?=$|\.)' } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group |
      Sort-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_O(?=$|\.)', '_0' } -Descending |
      Select-Object -Skip 3
  } |
  Move-Item -Destination old
```

Stick a `-WhatIf` on the `MoveItem` to see what's being done without actually changing anything. As an example:

```
H:\Stuff\54664753> ls

    Directory:  H:\Stuff\54664753

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-----       2019-02-13     10:10        1   old
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_A.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_B.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_C.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_D.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_O.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file2_A.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file2_O.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file3_O.xml
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file_A.txt
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file_B.txt
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file_C.txt
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file_O.txt

H:\Stuff\54664753> Get-ChildItem |
>>>   Group-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_[A-O](?=$|\.)' } |
>>>   ForEach-Object {
>>>     $_.Group |
>>>       Sort-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_O(?=$|\.)', '_0' } -Descending |
>>>       Select-Object -Skip 2
>>>   } |
>>>   Move-Item -Destination old -Whatif
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: H:\Stuff\54664753\1409-EM-M-PL-7000_B.dwg.pdf Destination: H:\Stuff\54664753\old\1409-EM-M-PL-7000_B.dwg.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: H:\Stuff\54664753\1409-EM-M-PL-7000_A.dwg.pdf Destination: H:\Stuff\54664753\old\1409-EM-M-PL-7000_A.dwg.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: H:\Stuff\54664753\1409-EM-M-PL-7000_O.dwg.pdf Destination: H:\Stuff\54664753\old\1409-EM-M-PL-7000_O.dwg.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: H:\Stuff\54664753\file_A.txt Destination: H:\Stuff\54664753\old\file_A.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: H:\Stuff\54664753\file_O.txt Destination: H:\Stuff\54664753\old\file_O.txt".
```

You can also try out the individual steps by shortening the pipeline appropriately, e.g. only the initial grouping:

```
H:\Stuff\54664753> Get-ChildItem |
>>>   Group-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_[A-O](?=$|\.)' }

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 old                       {old}
    5 1409-EM-M-PL-7000.dwg     {1409-EM-M-PL-7000_A.dwg.pdf, 1409-EM-M-PL-7000_B.dwg.pdf, 1409-EM-M-PL-7000_C.dwg.pdf, 1409-EM-M-PL-7000_D.dwg.pdf...}
    2 file2                     {file2_A.pdf, file2_O.pdf}
    1 file3                     {file3_O.xml}
    4 file                      {file_A.txt, file_B.txt, file_C.txt, file_O.txt}
```

Or grouping and sorting, but not the rest:

```
H:\Stuff\54664753> Get-ChildItem -File |
>>>   Group-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_[A-O](?=$|\.)' } |
>>>   ForEach-Object {
>>>     $_.Group |
>>>       Sort-Object { $_.Basename -creplace '_O(?=$|\.)', '_0' } -Descending
>>>   }

    Directory:  H:\Stuff\54664753

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_D.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_C.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_B.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_A.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:02        0   1409-EM-M-PL-7000_O.dwg.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file2_A.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file2_O.pdf
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file3_O.xml
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file_C.txt
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file_B.txt
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file_A.txt
-a----       2019-02-13     10:11        0   file_O.txt
```